# on click function not getting called

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to not display element after it was clicked, but the onclick method gets called when the page loads and then it does not get called when I click it. This is my code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".close").on('click', function(){
        $(this).parent().parent().css("display","none");
    });
}
```

What's the problem here?

Comment: Please share your html code....

Comment: because you have the function inside `ready`. you need to move it out

Comment: _"but the onclick method gets called when the page loads and then it does not get called when I click it."_ How could the `click` handler be called and you are still able to click the element?

Comment: @GowthamShiva _"because you have the function inside `ready`. you need to move it out"_?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Is the element (`.close`) present when the page loads? You can't bind an event like `click` to an element that isn't present when the page loads unless you delegate the event to a containing parent element that is present (e.g `body`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is unclear. But your element is either not available on the dom from the beginning or you have not selected properly the element you want to hide.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on('click', '.close',function(){
        $(this).closest("insert-element-name").css("display","none");
    });
}
```

Comment: may be he is clicking before the body is loaded

Comment: That's what I wanted. Thank you.